# Covering a chessboard with L-tetrominoes

Tags: checkerboard, tiling

We all know the [classic puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/255/5373) of trying to tile a mutilated chessboard with $2\times1$ dominoes. Let's imagine that, instead of dominoes, we have $n^2$ L-shaped tetrominoes and we want to tile a $2n\times2n$ chessboard using them (in any orientation, i.e. we're allowed to turn and flip tetrominoes if required). **For which values of $n$ is this possible?**

<sub>I got the idea for this from a question in the Danish Mathematical Olympiad.</sub>

Comment: Well, this question has a *checkered* past...

Comment: @Rubio no option to downvote comments :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, notice that

> we can put two L-tetrominoes together to make a 4x2 block, and that such blocks will do the job whenever $n$ is even.

Next,

> suppose $n$ is odd; then we have an odd number of tetrominoes. Now, colour the rows of our chessboard alternately red and blue; however you place an L-tetromino it will cover either 1 or 3 red squares; therefore the number of red squares covered has the same parity as the number of tetrominoes and is therefore odd. But in fact there are $2n^2$ red squares, an even number. So the covering can't be done for odd $n$.

In conclusion, the covering is possible if and only if

> $n$ is even.

Comment: Note: I changed the argument in my second spoiler block a bit a while after posting. I think the change is a small but definite improvement, but of course opinions may vary.

Answer (score 1):

> The total area will be $4n^2$, so the board is a $2nx2n$ one. If $2n$ is divisible by 4 ($n$ being even), it can be completed by building 4x2 rectangles to combine into such a board with 2 tetrominoes each.

Otherwise...

> If $n$ is odd, an odd number of tetrominoes will be used. Paint the square this way:
>  ....................
>  4...1...2...3... 
>  3...4...1...2... 
>  2...3...4...1... 
>  1...2...3...4... 
>  The different rotations and flips of the tetromino can be written like this: 
> [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmE6Y.png) 
>  In the shapes in the lower half of the picture, some numbers are repeated, but all the numbers must be distributed equally throughout the square. For every given $a$, there are two kinds of those shapes. 
>  $m_1 = p_{-3} + p_{3}$ 
>  $m_2 = r_{-3} + r_{3}$ 
>  $m_3 = s_{-3} + s_{3}$ 
>  $m_4 = t_{-3} + t_{3}$ 
>  $p_{-3}+ p_{3} + 2r_{-3} + s_{-3} + s_{3} + 2t_{3} = s_{-3}+ s_{3} + 2t_{-3} + p_{-3} + p_{3} + 2r_{3}$ 
>  $2r_{-3} + 2t_{3} = 2r_{3} + 2t_{-3}$ 
>  $r_{-3} + t_{3} = r_{3} + t_{-3} => m_2 + m_4$ is even (by the same token, so is $m_1 + m_3$). 
>  If the latter-half tetrominoes are used an even number of times, the number of the rest must be odd, but the opposite can be said when we flip the square vertically, creating a contradiction.

In short:

> The square can be made if and only if $n$ is even.